# How to add time with data?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, reshape

I have the data in the following format

[image]

By reshaping it using

```
data2 <- melt(data, id.vars=c('NAME_3'), variable.name = "T", value.name = "response")
```

[image]

I first created the sequence of date to be added in the table.

```
date = seq(from = as.Date("2012-10-01"), to = as.Date("2012-10-04"), by = 'day')
```

And then merge it with reshaped data

```
merge(data2, date)
```

[image]

But the Required result is

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but you are trying to merge with date when you don't have a predefined date already in the database? How is it supposed to match them? No matter what you would get the same result for every date. Are we missing some data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a group by operation i.e. after grouping by 'NAME_3', create the `seq`uence of 'date' with the `from` option and specify the `length.out` as `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
data2 <-  data2 %>%
      group_by(NAME_3) %>%
      mutate(date = seq(from = as.Date("2012-10-01"), 
                length.out = n(), by = 'day'))
```

NOTE: This should also work fine when there are unequal number of replications

---

Or if the number of rows for 'Name_3' elements are fixed, then we can use `rep`

```
data2$date <- rep(date, each = nrow(data))
```

This would return the data in the same `order` as the original `melt` dataset

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Can you explain what does "length.out=n()" means?

Comment: @fearsome `seq(Sys.Date(), length.out = 5, by = 'day')` i.e. this will return 5 dates from the current day incrementing by '1 day'.  In the dataset, the `n()` implies the number of rows per group.  If it is fixed, you can specify 5, but in most case, it can be variable.  So, used `n()`

Answer (score 0):

We can use recycling technique to add date column in `data2`.

Order the data by `Name_3` and assign `date` as new column.

```
data2 <- data2[order(data2$Name_3), ]
data2$date <- date
```